Which folders are synced with iCloud?
I'm thinking about upgrading to the 2TB iCloud plan and therefore start syncing my Desktop and Documents to iCloud.
I was wondering, since no info is given on this matter, what's going to happen to other folders in my user folder (such as the Pictures, the Videos and the Music folders). Are they going to be synced too, or will I have to very untidily move everything to subfolders inside the Documents folder?
Will it also work as computer backup in case my laptop is stolen? For example: will my curated font collection (currently living inside ~/Library/Fonts) or my command line program configuration files (currently in dot name folders in my user directory) be backed up to iCloud?
I find this "Desktop and documents" wording extremely confusing and I need a simple explanation.

Over and above using iCloud to back up your mac, using Time Machine is your best option to prevent data loss if your laptop is stolen or becomes damaged and unusable. If you're not using Time Machine, get an inexpensive external storage device and set it up ASAP.  Having multiple TM disks which can be taken offsite decreases the probability of loss. For the iCloud folder backups, one of the key features is that this content is available on all Apple devices, (Macs, tablets and mobile,) using the same iCloud account.

Nothing is going to happen to them.  The option does what it says, syncs your Desktop folder and your Documents folder with iCloud.  No other folders.
If you have pictures, video, and music, and do not use the Apple facilities for those (Photos and Music), then you have to place them in iCloud Drive yourself.
Your collection of fonts, you will need to provide a backup for them.
For your dotfiles, many people keep theirs in Github.  There are as many solutions for doing that as there are people doing it.  I have had success with the technique described at https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/dotfiles .
iCloud is most certainly not a backup, and Apple tells you so.  You should make regular backups, whether with Time Machine, or some other facility.

Thanks a lot for the clear answer.
Compared to how iCloud works on iOS this is terribly confusing. The fact of not syncing also the other documents folders (Pictures, Videos and Music) seems honestly dumb.

@gio91ber Just to add to emphasise last paragraph, if you use 2TB iCloud and a smaller system disk you do need to think carefully about how will do backup - it is not simple.

@gio91ber Apple thinks you should want to use Photos and Music.  Regarding how iCloud works on iOS, I don't see any particular difference between the two.  If you don't use iCloud Photo Library, Photos don't sync on either iOS or macOS, ditto for iCloud Music Library.
